Spring cloud spring-cloud-starter-parent as parent POM for microservices
What's better to use as parent POM in microservices architecture:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.18</version>
</parent>

or
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2022.0.2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

services register in Eureka server, Spring cloud gateway also is used. From my point of view its better to use spring-boot-starter-parent(potentially service discovery or gateway can be changed) but may be I'm wrong and and here its better to use spring-cloud-starter-parent(it uses spring-boot-starter-parent as parent). thanks in advance

Always use spring boot starter parent. We discourage using the cloud parent.

spring-cloud-starter-parent  is parent pom provided by spring cloud that extends  spring-boot-starter-parent with additional dependencies and configuration for spring cloud project.
If your application is not using any spring cloud feature , use spring-boot-starter-parent.
If your application requires spring cloud component like Eureka,Spring Cloud Config for configuration use spring-cloud-starter-parent.This will ensure compatibility and  dependency management for both spring boot and spring cloud libraries.

We discourage this usage pattern

What if application uses only a few spring cloud components: Eureka, API Gateway?) whats better suit in this case?
